# Why does my vhosts match without the domain name?

Tags: apache

I've configured my `httpd-vhosts.conf` file as follows:

```
<VirtualHost seg.localhost:81>
    ServerAdmin my@email.com
    DocumentRoot "D:\path\to\public_html"
    ServerName http://seg.localhost
    ServerAlias http://seg.localhost
    ErrorLog "logs/seg.log"
    CustomLog "logs/seg" common
    <directory "D:\path\to\public_html">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from all
    </directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

But when I go to `http://localhost:81/` in my browser, it's still hitting that folder. Why is the subdomain ignored?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using name based vhosts, the top-most vhost (the first instance of a `<VirtualHost>` block) is considered the *"default"* vhost, meaning that if a request is made for a host that doesn't match any of the given `<VirtualHost>`'s, the top-most one is used.

You can get around this by adding a new top-most vhost that simply denies everything:

```
<VirtualHost seg.localhost:81>
   ServerName _default_
   DocumentRoot "D:\path\to\public_html"
   <Directory "D:\path\to\public_html">
      Order Allow,Deny
      Deny from all
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Or have it redirect to seg.localhost, or however you want to handle it.